# Adding functionality to a JavaScript Calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, calendar

I have downloaded a JavaScript and jQuery calendar from the site CodeCanyon, [link to calendar preview](http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-events-calendar-js/full_screen_preview/462149?ref=slowboy), and I am trying to put it on to a website for my work.

The work site is written in ASPX and I am replacing the current "read only" calendar tied to Outlook that is in an iframe with this calendar. I am currently writing the calendar into an html page, but still haven't figured out how to add the functionality of adding events.

How do I add the ability for a user to add an event to the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin lacks documentation badly, still we can manage to get the options by inspecting source code, which are self-explanatory.

First we need to  make an `array` to store events and after we set it in `events_array` option, here is the Javascript code for the example you sent with events data and how to set in the calendar object:

```
var events_array = new Array({
    startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
    endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
    title: "Event 1",
    description: "Description 1",
    priority: 2, // 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, 3 = Urgent
    frecuency: 1 // 1 = Daily, 2 = Weekly, 3 = Monthly, 4 = Yearly
}, {
    startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 9, 50),
    title: "Event 3",
    description: "Description 3",
    priority: 3,
    frecuency: 3
});
$(".selector").dp_calendar({
    events_array: events_array
});
```

In other words, having a database with the events saved from user input data, you only need to loop through records adding items to this `array` or retrieve all in JSON format.